# nvd3: How highlight whole stacked bar on mouseover?

Tags: javascript, charts, d3.js, nvd3.js

I need to highlight whole stacked bar on nvd3 chart to show a common tooltip with values of the whole bar.

My code is the same of the example: http://nvd3.org/ghpages/multiBar.html

Comment: There's no option for this in NVD3, so you would have to modify the source code.

Comment: Have cloned multibar chart model, is possible by manually highlight on `multibar.dispatch.on('elementMouseover.tooltip')` event? Or have to modify `multibar` component?

Comment: I'm not sure about the details of the modifications, but it's not a simple change -- you would have to select and highlight the other bars on mouseover of one of the bars as well as changing what's displayed in the toolip.

Answer (score 0):

for the highlight, put in your css something like this:

```
 .nv-bar:hover {
     fill: #ff0000 //this is bright red, pick the highlight color you want
 }
```

A tooltip would probably best be implemented with javascript or jQuery. Use their event system to pop display an element on mouseover, move it to your mouse and fill it with the appropriate data. Hide it on mouseleave.

Comment: because by default when the chart is rendered the style is inline which overrides any css styles. In your css you need to define it as fill: #ff0000!important for the style to take effect